# IdentityServer4, IResourceStore.GetAllResources()

Tags: identityserver4

I am looking at building a class implementing the IdentityServer `IResourceStore` interface. My goal is to serve `IdentityResource` and `ApiResource` collections as defined in a custom repository.

Ideally, I will receive requests for these resources and respond with the subset relevant to the query. In short: You only get what you ask for.

The `GetAllResources()`method makes me leery: Is IdentityServer actually requiring that I pull the entire set of my Identity and API resources from my repository and make this available? At this point I have no idea how large those collections will grow, or the cost of pulling them from the repository.

What are the consequences of simply responding with a null or empty lists of resources?

-S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used in the `GetAllEnabledResourcesAsync` method in the `IResourceStoreExtensions` class, which in turn is used by the `DiscoveryEndpoint`. So, if you don't implement this method the Discovery endpoint will not be able to display any scopes or claims.

By don't implement I mean return some empty lists or something, not throw a `NotImplementedException` or return null... That would break everything.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!